# what vscode ruby extension detects things like undeclared variables?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

I've been trying many extensions/configurations but can't get vscode to detect when a variable is undefined. For example, something simple like this shows no alerts:

```
# b and c are not defined anywhere
a = b + c
```

I'd hope to see the linter or other extensions alert me that b and c are not declared. Instead I'm not seeing any highlighting or notification at all.

I've installed the following extensions: Ruby, Solargraph, ruby-linter, ruby-robocop, VSCode Ruby. I've added some custom configs for linter, solargraph and intellisense:

```
"ruby.linter.run": "onSave",
"solargraph.definitions": false,
"ruby.intellisense": "rubyLocate"
```

but still nothing has worked. Any help is appreciated

Comment: That's not an easy thing to do in Ruby. `b` and `c` could be method calls and those methods could be defined almost anywhere at any time so you don't really know if they're defined or not until you try to use them.

Comment: You might find [this article](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/10/defined-keyword/) of interest.

Comment: @muistooshort that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm familiar with checking if a variable is defined. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As mu says, checking if an identifier is defined at some point of execution is easy. Checking if an identifier is defined without running the program (i.e. static code analysis) is not. Consider this valid code: `%i(b c).each_with_index { |v, i| define_singleton_method(v) { i + 1 } }; a = b + c; puts a` How would VSCode know?

Answer (score 2):

Solargraph has an experimental type checker that you can activate in a `.solargraph.yml` file:

```
reporters:
- typecheck:strict
```

Keep in mind, you're likely to get false positives because 1) it's still in beta, and 2) as other people have mentioned, dynamic methods and other runtime magic are often invisible to static analysis.

More information: https://solargraph.org/guides/type-checking